# vb.net Function return nothing

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, dataset

I want a function that returns a string, for example "AirForce".

Code like below. But it returns Nothing.

Need Help.

```
Dim CLWorkGroup As String = DALC.GetDALC.GetWorkGroupByAssignmentID(strAssignmentID, objJobOrderDetailGUID)

Public Function GetWorkGroupByAssignmentID(ByVal id As String, ByVal guid As Guid) As String
    Return DirectCast(Me._objJobAssignmentTableAdapter.JobAssignmentGetWorkGroupByAssignmentID(id, guid), String)
End Function
```

Stored procedure:

```
Alter PROCEDURE dbo.JobAssignmentGetWorkGroupByAssignmentID
(
  @AssignmentID AS NVARCHAR,
  @Guid uniqueidentifier
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT     CLWorkGroup
FROM       JobAssignment
WHERE     (AssignmentID = @AssignmentID) AND (JobOrderDtlID=@Guid)
GO
```

[Added breakpoint and its values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxBzG.jpg)

Comment: Try adding some breakpoints to see what data is being passed around.

Comment: Possible issue with using a guid and SQL string. As @TheWhiteWolf said, add break point, get a few data values, plug them into the sproc, confirm you are getting the data you want returned.

Comment: It could be that `_objJobAssignmentTableAdapter.JobAssignmentGetWorkGroupByAssignmentID` is not working as you expect. It might help us if you showed the code for that function.

Comment: Hi All...Is a Table Adapter problem. Thanks Much.